# Выдает ошибку при запросе

Tags: php

Не могу понять, в чем происходит ошибка... Сам код:

```
$ip=$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$id = $_GET['id'];

if(isset($id))  {
    $result = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO rate (id, from, action) VALUES ('$id','$ip','+1')");

    if ($result === true) {
        $text = "Рейтинг истории успешно повышен";
    }

    else {
        $text = "Ошибка!";
    }
}
else {
    $text = "Отсутсвует ID";
}
```

Выводит ошибку

> Ошибка!

Значит проблема в sql запросе? Там вроде все в порядке, таблица есть, столбцы есть, к бд подключена. Сам id принимает.

Сам запрос вида domen.loc/file.php?id=idnum

Answer (score 2):

Учите матчасть, посмотрите определение функции [mysql query](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php), она возвращает ресурс, а не результат выполнения запроса. Вам после выполнения запроса необходимо выполнить функцию [mysql affected rows](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php), чтобы узнать, что запись действительно добавилась. Смотрите примеры в документации по ссылке.

З.Ы. а еще после выполнения запроса надо бы проверить, была ли ошибка.

Достаточно такой проверки:

```
$text = ($result) ? "Рейтинг истории успешно повышен" : "Ошибка!";
```

Answer (score 0):

1. проверьте на типы полей для бд и того что вы пытаетесь записать.
2. поля таблицы в кавычки, пользуемся нормальной библиотекой.

   ```
    $db=new PDO('$dsn', '$user', '$password');
    $req=$db->prepare("INSERT INTO `rate` SET `id`=?, `from`=?, `action`=? "     
    ,array($id,$ip,'+1'));
    $req->execute(array($table));
   ```

Comment: Типы полей varchar(255)
насчет запроса, то не очень понял, да и ругается на new PDO

Comment: смотря как ругается нужно верные данные указывать при инициализации, в запросе поля и имя таблицы должны быть обрамлены косыми кавычками, которые находятся на клавиатуре сразу под Esc в английской раскладке. а запрос обычный с плейсхолдерами

Comment: @rimlin, возможно, что просто не подключён PDO (или без него собрано, если вы под линуксом).

Answer (score -1):

не так
$result == 'true'

а так 
$result === true

Comment: Толку то, все равно в бд не вставляет запись

Comment: +1 в поле action зачем? и какой тип этого поля?

Comment: запрос вида domen.loc/file.php?id=idnum

Answer (score -1):

```
    if(isset($id))  {
    $result = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO `rate` (`id` ,`from` ,`action`)
     VALUES (
'".$id."', '".$ip."', '+1');");

if ($result == true) {
    $text = "Рейтинг истории успешно повышен";
}
```

Сколько писать нужно!!!

Пишите ВЫ КАВЫЧКИ! неужели так сложно? и вопроса бы не было. а первый ответивший прав вместо **===** просто **==**

Comment: Не помогло...

Comment: > '+1' 

почему +1 а не просто 1? в чем фишка? поставь туда 1 или 0, или 2,3,4,5 поле ** какого типа? INTEGER? если да, то запрос никогда не выполнится!**

Comment: поле varchar(255), можно сделать и 1 
$result = mysql_query ("INSERT INTO rate (id, from, action) VALUES ('".$id."','".$ip."','1')");
Все равно, не помогло, запись не вставляется.

Comment: Попробуй еще раз, обновил ответ.